# Best way to send email when PHP process dies

Tags: email, nginx, php

I wrote a quick PHP page to handle 502 requests. Nginx will re-direct to this page when a 502 is encountered and an email is fired off.

The problem is, most of the time that the 502 is encountered is because PHP has died, so writing to the DB and sending an email using PHP is no longer possible. Tweaks to PHP-FPM settings have done a lot to help (restarting PHP, etc), but I'd still like a fall-back.

There are numerous ways to send an email outside of PHP, but I am curious what others out there are doing with good success? I'd like to keep it simple for configuration (i.e. not have yet another complex dependency to worry about on the servers) and reliability reasons.

Googling and searching SO didn't turn up much, probably because "dies" and "fail" bring back a lot of false positives for my scenario.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx config, but how about configuring the 502 handler to be a cgi script? Then you can have it execute the php cli binary directly, which always spawns a nice fresh unadulterated process.

Comment: This is a great idea. Nginx does not support CGI out of the box, but you can proxy to another web server that does. After doing some research, [thttpd](http://acme.com/software/thttpd/) will fit my needs. I need to continue to play around with it, but I can set up a simple bash script to call the PHP cli to parse my PHP script. The additional benefit is that I don't have to write anything new and I get all the same functionality the script already provides.

Comment: be sure to post what you end up with - all those upvotes on your question means ppl wanna see an answer(you can answer your own question).

Comment: @iputonmyrobeanwizardhat I'm pretty sure you could also execute a command-line script from that handler which can of course also be a PHP script.

Comment: Another thought: You could also configure rsyslogd to execute a script on messages that match the syslog line when PHP crashes.

Comment: I would suggest to use this shell script , but you need to customize it to add php-fpm support http://bash.cyberciti.biz/monitoring/monitor-unix-linux-network-services/

Comment: You should to monitor a PHP process as linux process. A way to do that is to use the http://ps-watcher.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've ended up doing. I've not rolled it out to our prod servers yet, but all testing thus far looks good.

Nginx does not support CGI natively, so you need another means to do it. [thttpd](http://acme.com/software/thttpd/) fit the bill nicely. There is a good write up the nginx [wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/ThttpdCGI) showing how to use it.

I configured thttpd with the following:

```
dir=/var/www/htdocs
user=thttpd
logfile=/var/log/thttpd.log
pidfile=/var/run/thttpd.pid
port=8000
cgipat=**.cgi
```

And added this to my nginx config:

```
error_page 502 @thttpd;

location @thttpd {
    include proxy.include;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

Finally, I created a basic CGI script that calls PHP on the command line and passed in my already-written PHP script. This was an ideal solution for me because the script was already set up to log to our alerts table and fire off an email. This is also real-time, as the script will execute as soon as nginx returns a 502 code (subsequent 502s will not hammer me with emails, per the logic of the script).

I was able to run some simulation tests be forcing nginx to return a 502 (see more [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/165929/simulate-502-504-on-nginx)).

I'm going to continue tweaking this, but I'm pretty happy with the relative ease of deploying it and that I could re-use existing code.

Answer (score 1):

What about use a cronjob (bash based) to parse error_log file periodically (x hours) and send an email (mutt/mail) when find something like `resuming normal operations` in the last period (x hours). I think is simple and effective...

```
[Thu Dec 27 14:37:52 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 27 14:37:53 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.6-2~precise+1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

**UPDATE:**

@Brian As @takeshin says cronjobs can run even every second if you want, but some sysadmins could bite you... :|

Comment: This is a certainly a good idea, but won't fit my needs. I am looking for a real-time notification. I need to know as soon as a 502 is encountered, not potentially X hours later.

Comment: @brian I hope you find a solution. All which we have upvoted your question are expecting... Good Luck.

Comment: @Brian You may set cron to run each second, thats ~real time. But real time notifications may be dangerous if someone discovers how to trigger an error sending the email, your mailbox will be flooded. See `Zend_Log` for different levels of error logging.

Answer (score 0):

We have  dual solution.

We use shell script to send out email notifications, if PHP dies. We check if php service is running with shell command in the shell script, if it is not running, we'll fire off a shell command to send an email.

This is all in a few lines of Shell Script. Not too hard.

Of course, set it up in cron.